# Como fazer uma div que esta oculta aparecer ao clicar em um botão aparecer e depois ocultar com o tempo

Tags: javascript, html5

Tô tentando fazer uma `div` como se fosse um `alert`, preciso que ela apareça quando eu clicar em um botão pois ela inicia oculta, e quando ela aparecer comesse contar um tempo para a mesma sumir.

```
<div id="alertcart" style="display:none;" class="alert">
    Produto adicionado ao carrinho!
</div>
```

Aqui em cima é a `div` em questão, acredito que o processionamento deve ser feito com java script, peço uma luz a alguém de como eu poderia fazer isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz uma versão com jQuery que usa um `fadeIn/Out` e `setTimeout` fazer o `fadeIn` do `.alert` quando clica no botão, e o `setTimeout` conta 2 segundo antes de fazer o `fadeOut` do `.alert`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
$(function(){
  $('#box').on('click', function(){
 var mv = $('.alert');
 mv.fadeIn();
    setTimeout(function(){
      mv.fadeOut();
    }, 2000)
  })
});
```

```css
.alert {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script> 

<button id="box" type="button">Mostra Alert</button>


  <div id="alertcart" class="alert">
    Produto adicionado ao carrinho!
  </div>
```